# Does Datadog support runtime code instrumentation?

Tags: .net, datadog, apm

I am looking at some alternatives for APM and I like the extensive list of Datadog integration points.  However, it seems that I would have to make code changes to explicitly send stats to Datadog.  Doesn't Datadog support runtime instrumentation?  My tech stack is MS .NET/C# and SQL Server backend.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am on the same boat. I found this link: [datadog instrumentation](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/#instrument-your-application).
So, currently (20.11.2017) there are not agents for C#. Only Go, python and ruby are available.

[image: screenshot 20.11.2017]

Answer (score 0):

(Disclosure: I'm a software developer at Datadog.)

Datadog's open-source .NET Tracer is currently (2019-02-11) in open beta. It supports manual and automatic instrumentation and [OpenTracing](https://opentracing.io/guides/csharp/).

- [GitHub](https://github.com/DataDog/dd-trace-dotnet)
- [Official docs](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/languages/dotnet)

For a list of currently supported languages/frameworks, see the [updated documentation](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/languages/).

Happy tracing!